# What is the "munch"? How it was used with cfront

Tags: c++, c, cfront

What was the munch library (or program?) from `cfront` package?
What is was used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Munch was used to scan the nm output and look for static constructors/destructors.

See the [code](http://www.softwarepreservation.com/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_3.0.3/source/Munch/munch.c/view) (with comments) at [SoftwarePreservation.com](http://www.softwarepreservation.com/).

Comment: the link is visited, but i did not get the functionality of munch after looking at code.

Comment: I suspect this is what `collect2` does for GCC.

Answer (score 1):

"Munching" is not specific to `cfront`.

In C++, your constructors and destructors are called implicitly based on their lifetime.
Global static objects have a lifetime of the whole program.
If you have multiple global static objects across various translation units,
who gets constructed first?

That is up to the compiler, and it is often dubbed [The Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).
Normally you wouldn't care about construction order, but if your objects have lifetime dependencies on each other, it can end up biting you.  See the following FAQ on [idiomatically avoiding SIOF](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use).

With all that being said, the "muncher" is a c code generator.
You give all of your c++ object files to the name mangler,
and forward the name mangler's output into the muncher.
`*.o -> nm -> muncher -> *.c`

Typical implementations will generate two function tables
(an array of function pointers to the constructors and destructors)
+ a bit of assembly to make sure they get called.

There are times when you want to tell the linker specifically what order to initialize,
and that's where the muncher comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it [extracts initializers and finalizers](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/exp/glast/flight/sw/vxdocs/tornado/hutils/munch.html).